# React-Native Printing issue

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

My Receipt Print code is:

// ReceiptPage.js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { AntDesign, FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { colors, mainStyle } from '../../Style';

import * as Print from 'expo-print';

const ReceiptPage = ({ vehicleData, onCancel }) => {
const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = React.useState(0);

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    setTotalPrice(calculateTotalFinePrice(vehicleData.fines) + vehicleData.fee);
}, [vehicleData.fines, vehicleData.fee]);

const handlePrint = async () => {
    try {
        await Print.printAsync({
            html: generateReceiptHTML(),
            width: 72 / 1.33,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error while printing:', error);
        // Handle printing error (e.g., show a message to the user)
    }
};

const generateReceiptHTML = () => {
    const receiptHTML = `
        <style>
            /* Styles moved to the stylesheet */
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            .receipt {
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 12px;
                line-height: 1.5;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 10px;
                border: 1px solid #000;
                width: 72mm !important;
                justify-content: left
            }
            
            .header {
                text-align: center;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }
            div{
                margin:0;
            }
            .violation ul {
                list-style-type: none;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }
            .violation p,
            .payment p{
                text-align: justify
            }

            .contact a {
                color: blue;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            .contact p{
                text-align: justify;
                font-size: 10px;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="receipt">
            <div class="header">
                <h2>ICE Parküberwachung</h2>
                <p>Unkompliziert und sicher</p>
            </div>
            <p>Parkverstoß & Zahlungsaufforderung</p>
            <br />
            <div class="content">
                <p>Datum: ${vehicleData.date} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Uhrzeit: ${vehicleData.entryTime}</p>
                <br />
                <p>Vorgangsnummer: ${vehicleData.invoiceNumber}</p>
                <p>Kennzeichen: ${vehicleData.vehicleNumber}</p>
                <p>Modell: ${vehicleData.vehicleModel} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Farbe: ${vehicleData.vehicleColor}</p>
                <br />
                <p>Mitarbeiternummer: ${vehicleData.employeeName}</p>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="location">
                <p>Ort:</p>
                <p>Wuppertal,</p>
                <p>Friedrich-Ebert-Str. 154B,</p>
                <p>42117 Wuppertal</p>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="violation">
                <p>Verstoß:</p>
                <p>Der/Die Fahrer/-in hat auf einem Privatgelände geparkt und gegen die Allgemeinen
                    Geschäftsbedingungen (AGB) von ICE Parküberwachung wie folgt verstoßen:
                </p>
                <br />
                ${vehicleData.fines && vehicleData.fines.length > 0 ?
            `<ul>
                        ${vehicleData.fines.map((fine, index) => `<li>${fine.type}</li>`).join('')}
                    </ul>` :
            '<p>Keine Strafen enthalten</p>'
        }
                <br />
                <p>Die Allgemeinen Geschäftsbedingungen werden auf den Hinweisschildern (mindestens an den Zufahrten) erwähnt.
                </p>

                <br />
                <p><b>Vertragsstrafe:</b> ${totalPrice} €</p>
                <br />
            </div>
            <div class="payment">
                <p>
                    Bei Nichtzahlung oder falschem Verwendungszweck droht eine gerichtliche Einforderung der
                    Forderung, was zu zusätzlichen erheblichen Kosten führt, die ebenfalls vom Verursacher zu tragen
                    sind. Bitte überweisen Sie umgehend, spätestens jedoch innerhalb von 10 Tagen, ${totalPrice} € auf das
                    folgende Konto:
                </p>
                <br/>
                <b>
                <p>ICE Parküberwachung</p>
                <p>Sparkasse Remscheid</p>
                <p>DE25 3405 0000 0000 1371 17</p>
                </b>
                <br/>
                <p>Verwendungszweck:</p>
                <p>${vehicleData.invoiceNumber} + ${vehicleData.vehicleNumber}
                </p>
                <p><u>(Angaben zwingend erforderlich)</u></p>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="contact">
                <p>Kontakt:</p>
                <p>
                    Bei Fragen und Anregungen kontaktieren Sie uns bitte unter
                    <br />
                    www.ice-parkueberwachung.de/kontakt
                </p>
                <br/>
                <p>Der Schutz Ihrer Privatsphäre bei der Verarbeitung personenbezogener Daten und die Sicherheit aller Geschäftsdaten sind uns wichtig und werden in unseren Geschäftsprozessen berücksichtigt.
                Wir behandeln personenbezogene Daten vertraulich und gemäß den gesetzlichen Vorgaben.
                </p>
                </br>
                <p>
                Weitere Informationen zur Verarbeitung Ihrer Daten durch ICE Parküberwachung und Ihre datenschutzrechtlichen Rechte finden Sie unter</p>
                <p>www.ice-parkueberwachung.de/datenschutz</p>

                </br>
                <p>By parking your car in this location, you have not adhered to the parking regulations in the area of ICE Park Monitoring. Therefore, you are obliged to pay the penalty specified on the ticket within 10 days via bank transfer, stating the reference number ${vehicleData.invoiceNumber} of the ticket.</p>
                
                </br>
                <p>ICE Parküberwachung</p>
                <p>Eschenbeekerstr 9B</p>
                <p>42109 Wuppertal</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    `;
    return receiptHTML;
};

const calculateTotalFinePrice = (fines) => {
    if (!fines || fines.length === 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    return fines.reduce((total, fine) => total + parseFloat(fine.price), 0);
};

function printToConsole(message) {
  // Use setTimeout to add a delay between print requests
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(message);
  }, 5000); // Wait 5000 milliseconds before printing
}

printToConsole("First message");
printToConsole("Second message");
printToConsole("Third message");

return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
            <Text style={styles.label}>ICE Parküberwachung Receipt:</Text>
            <AntDesign name="close" size={24} color={colors.mainText} onPress={onCancel} />
        </View>
        <ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.receipt}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Rechnungsnummer: {vehicleData.invoiceNumber}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Datum: {vehicleData.date}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Zeit: {vehicleData.entryTime}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Fahrzeugnummer: {vehicleData.vehicleNumber}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Fahrzeugmodell: {vehicleData.vehicleModel}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Fahrzeugfarbe: {vehicleData.vehicleColor}</Text>
                {!vehicleData.isParked ?
                    <Text style={styles.label}>Fee: {vehicleData.fee}</Text>
                    : (
                        <Text style={styles.label}>Parked</Text>
                    )}
                {vehicleData.fines && vehicleData.fines.length > 0 ? (
                    <>
                        <Text style={mainStyle.subHeading}>Liste der Strafen: </Text>
                        {vehicleData.fines.map((fine, index) => (
                            <View key={index}>
                                <Text style={{ color: colors.mainText }}>{index + 1}. Typ: {fine.type}</Text>
                                <Text style={{ color: colors.mainText }}>Preis: {fine.price} <FontAwesome name="euro" size={16} color={colors.mainText} /></Text>
                                <Text style={{ color: colors.mainText }}>Beschreibung: {fine.description}</Text>
                            </View>
                        ))}
                    </>
                ) : (
                    <Text>Alle Strafen werden hier angezeigt</Text>
                )}
                <Text style={styles.label}>{`Total Price: ${totalPrice}`} <FontAwesome name="euro" size={16} color={colors.mainText} /></Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePrint}>
                    <Text style={mainStyle.secondaryButton}>Drucken</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
);
```

};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
width: "100%",
height: "60%",
backgroundColor: colors.bg,
position: "absolute",
bottom: 0,
overflow: "hidden",
borderRadius: 10,
borderWidth: 1,
borderColor: colors.border,
margin: 0,
padding: 0,
shadowOffset: { width: 2, height: 4 },
shadowOpacity: 0.2,
shadowRadius: 3,
},
header: {
backgroundColor: colors.primary,
width: "100%",
display: "flex",
flexDirection: "row",
justifyContent: "space-between",
paddingHorizontal: 20,
paddingVertical: 10,
borderBottomWidth: 2,
borderBottomColor: colors.border,
},
label: {
fontSize: 18,
fontWeight: "bold",
},
receipt: {
padding: 20
},
text: {
fontSize: 18,
fontWeight: "bold",
color: colors.secondaryText,
textTransform: "capitalize",
textAlign: "left",
},
});

export default ReceiptPage;

Comment: I have faced the issue in Android(version 14), using "expo-print" .that is "Another print request is already in progress", but this issue occurs intermittently, but once this issue occurs it won't allow any consequent prints, need to manually close the application and it would work. So is there any way to clear the print queue or unmount the expo print when this issue occurs